Geo referencing in Julia
I have a heat map of a region over Los Angeles, stored as a matrix; however, the information is stored as pixels instead of as more convenient (lat, lon). Is there any way I can incorporate this into the map?
I have multiple images which do not overlap completely, and it would be convenient to access a common point on the images using their coordinates.

One solution is to use the Rasters package, create first a empty raster with the extent and crs of the image and then just assigne the raster values to the values of the image. After you have it as a Rasters.Raster object, it is easy to do any raster operation/spatial computation...
